Template type deduction include the const?
What I have:
template<typename T>
class Holder
{
    T&   held;
    public:
        Holder(T& h)
            : held(h)
        {}
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Holder const& data)
        {
             return stream << "Held"; // Actually pulls value from Holder data.held.stuff but not relevant to question.
        }
};

template<typename T>
Holder<T>  make_Holder(T& toHold)       {return Holder<T>(toHold);}

template<typename T>
Holder<T const> make_Holder(T const& toHold)  {return Holder<T const>(toHold);}

int main()
{
    std::cout << make_Holder(12);

    int value = 12;
    std::cout << make_Holder(value);
}

The above works.
BUT I have been trying to use a single make_Holder() function and automatically detect/forward the type (including the const) through into the Holder type returned. But can't quite seem to make it work. Any help appreciated.

top level const is discarded when deducing the template type.  What actual problem are you trying to solve?  Do note that const & class members do not extend the lifetime of a temporary object and std::cout << make_Holder(12); has UB since the return of make_holder refers to an object that has been destroyed.

Sorry, it doesn't havge UB since you never try to access held but if you did then it would.

So why didn't you use T&& in function if you want forwarding?

@NathanOliver Even if I accesses the value of the object it should be good (I think) as I do everything within the same expression. The temporary object will only be destroyed at the ;.

@Gene: I tried that but could not get it to compile. Holder<T> make_Holder(T&& toHold)               {return Holder<T>(std::forward<T>(toHold));}

@Loki Astari -- the answer below

@Gene: Ahhhhhh. When building my simpleified example I forgot to add -std=c++17 to the command line.

Currently make_Holder(12) creates a dangling pointer at end of full expression... Shouldn't held be T instead (and then use Holder<int&> for make_Holder(value))?

@Jarod42 In this example I am using int as an example. But T could be something large. Yes it would be dangling after the end of the expression but the Holder object itself is not used beyond the end of the expression it is simply used to call the operator<< to print the object to a stream. Once the object is printed the expression is over and the Holder disappears and thus no dangling reference lives on.

If it is just for printing (non-mutable function), why not use unconditionally const T&?

Perfect forwarding is the answer of course.
Made a simple mistake when building the simplified example (and forgot the -std=c++17 flag and missed it).
template<typename T>
class Holder
{
    T&   held;
    public:
        Holder(T&& h)
           //   ^^         Change Here.
            : held(h)
        {}
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Holder const& data)
        {
             return stream << "Held"; // Actually pulls value from Holder data.held.stuff but not relevant to question.
        }
};


// Forwarding here:
template<typename T>
Holder<T>  make_Holder(T&& toHold)       {return Holder<T>(std::forward<T>(toHold));}


int main()
{
    std::cout << make_Holder(12);

    int value = 12;
    std::cout << make_Holder(value);
}


It's more ugly than I initially thought, because of combination of template type deduction and the constructor taking a reference. The type deduction has to be more subtle. Here is a function that would add the const to the deduced type for rvalue reference:
template<typename T>
auto  make_Holder(T&& toHold) 
{
    if constexpr(std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>)
        return Holder<std::remove_reference_t<T>>(std::forward<T>(toHold));
    else
        return Holder<std::add_const_t<T>>
        (std::forward<T>(toHold));
}

Alternatively, you write a similar template deduction guide:
template<typename T>
Holder(T&&) -> Holder<std::conditional_t<
    std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>,
    std::remove_reference_t<T>,
    std::add_const_t<T>
    >>;

Caveat: though this code does what you get what you wanted, you should rethink your design. Because in case of rvalues, your class is holding a stale reference to the object that no longer exists.
